# How exactly mean this graph obtained by git log?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-log

I am absolutly new in **GIT** and I have the following doubt.

Into a project on which I am working on I do:

```
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/WS_vari/version-control/asteroids (master)
$ git branch
* master
```

So it should bean that I have only the **master** branch in this project. Is it my interpretation correct?

Then I want to see the graph related to the commitment of this project performing:

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate=full --all
```

and this is my output:

```
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/WS_vari/version-control/asteroids (master)
$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate=full --all
* cba1887 (HEAD -> refs/heads/master) fixing: fixed the bug related of the weapo
n delay
* 3884eab (refs/remotes/origin/master, refs/remotes/origin/HEAD) Add color
* 3e42136 now using requestAnimationFrame
* 4035769 frame interval was set wrong after game was paused
* 25ede83 a couple missing ends with the ipad version
* df03538 I can't spell 'screen' apparently :)
| * 354dfdd (refs/remotes/origin/coins) Make ships able to spawn on coins
| * 0c6daf1 Make it possible to collect coins
| * a3c0ae4 Create helper functions
| * 656b02e First pass at adding coins
|/
* b0678b1 Revert controls
* f19cb1b Fix typo in space
* 75928a9 Use space for movement and enter for shooting
* ac83b72 mostly finished ipad version
* 7ca4826 trying to get div touch controls to work

....................................................................
....................................................................
....................................................................
```

So I think that it means:

1) The last commit have id **cba1887** and this commit is into the **master** branch.

My problem is on this section of the graph:

```
* df03538 I can't spell 'screen' apparently :)
| * 354dfdd (refs/remotes/origin/coins) Make ships able to spawn on coins
| * 0c6daf1 Make it possible to collect coins
| * a3c0ae4 Create helper functions
| * 656b02e First pass at adding coins
|/
```

So it seems to me that it is creating a new branch having id **df03538** (the branch can have an ID or am I missing something?) and label **I can't spell 'screen' apparently :)**.

This branch contains 4 commits with ids **354dfdd, 0c6daf1, a3c0ae4, 656b02e**.

Is it my interpretation correct or am I missing something?

If my interpretation is correct and this is a new branch why I can't see it into the list of branches obtined by the previous **git branch** statment that show only the **master** branch?

Comment: Running `git branch` by itself only shows you *local* branches.  Run `git branch -a` to see both local and remote branches, which might help make more sense of things.

Comment: @larsks mmm what the difference between a local branch an a remote branch? can you give me more information about this stuff?

Comment: I refer you to [the git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) for answers, which includes an explicit discussion of [remote branches](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it my interpretation correct or am I missing something?

No, the line `* df03538 I can't spell 'screen' apparently :)`, is a unit which denotes a commit in your `master` branch.

Meanwhile, `* 354dfdd (refs/remotes/origin/coins) Make ships able to spawn on coins` is the last commit of the branch you talked about.

> why I can't see it into the list of branches obtained by the previous git branch statement that show only the master branch?

Here `refs/remotes/origin/coins` as the only ref means it's a remote branch, which you haven't checked out locally, you can actually see it via:

```
git branch -a
```

And, you can checkout it via:

```
git checkout -t origin/coins
```

This will create a local branch named `coins` which also tracks `origin/coins`, and you'll be able to see it via `git branch`.

Comment: So, from what I have understand reading the official documentation, a "remote branch" is a branch that is not on my local repository but that is on the remote repository. Is it correct?

Comment: Here a **remote branch** means a branch you have fetched (downloaded) from a remote repo (with associated commits), but haven't checked out locally. check it out and you make it a local branch.